# Panning of a map is not smooth in winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Combining the multiple small images *(256*256)* into a large image(dimensions of `picturebox`). Now if I am trying to pan / move the large image it is not moving until the difference is 256 pixels. Its not panning smoothly. Here is my code

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        if (isdragging)
        {
            mapCenterX += (-e.X + (startingpoint.X)) * Map.scaleX;

            mapCenterY -= (-e.Y + (startingpoint.Y)) * Map.scaleY;

            Map.DrawMap(mapCenterX, mapCenterY, mapZoom);

            startingpoint.X = e.X;
            startingpoint.Y = e.Y;
            pictureBox1.Invalidate();
        }
    }
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        isdragging = false;
    }
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        isdragging = true;
        startingpoint.X = e.X;
        startingpoint.Y = e.Y;
    }
}
```

Comment: To get quick and concise answers, make sure to share working/functional code instead of a small piece and expecting others to cook recipe first to find answers.

Comment: What is `Map.DrawMap(mapCenterX, mapCenterY, mapZoom);` Also: Is there a Paint event? Also: Why not make the combined images into one and set it at the PBox.Image??